# JS time calculation - How many times a date has occurred between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I really need some assistance with a time calculation in JS.

Put basically I need to calculate how many times a day of a month has occurred between two dates.

For Example -

A date of 15th of the month between 1st February 2014 to 14 May 2014 would be 3
A date of 15th of the month between 1st February 2014 to 16 May 2014 would be 4

I've looked at moment Jquery library but it estimates that a month is 30 days so I wouldn't be exact and take into consideration leap years - months with 28 days etc..

It really needs to be exact because its for a chargeable event calculation. The dates can spare many years so could lead to in-accuries because of the 30 day thing.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can use http://isaaccambron.com/twix.js/ if you are allowed to use moment.js. This will do exactly what you want without have to deal with 11:59:59 pm problems etc. or TZ issues you might have to consider.

Comment: Thanks amchang87 - im trying to use twix now but none of the functions seem to do what I need - what function did you htink would work in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a million ways to do this... here's a brute force way:

```
// add a "addDays() method to Date"
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days)
{
    var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
    return dat;
}

// provide two dates and a day ordinal you want to count between the two
function numOrdinalsBetweenDts(Date1, Date2, theOrdinal) {
    var temp;

    if(Date2 < Date1) {  // put dates in the right order (lesser first)
        temp = Date1;
        Date1 = Date2;
        Date2 = temp;
    }

    var workDate = Date1;
    var ctr = 0;
    while(workDate < Date2) {    // iterate through the calendar until we're past the end
        if(workDate.getDate() == theOrdinal)   // if we match the ordinal, count it
            ctr++;
        workDate = workDate.addDays(1);   // move the calendar forward a day
    }
    return ctr;
}


var result = numOrdinalsBetweenDts(new Date("July 21, 1901"), new Date("July 21, 2014"), 2);
console.log(result);
alert(result);
```

Comment: Adapted this slightly but works amazingly ! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

There is a slightly counter-intuitive behavior in the Javascript Date constructor where if you create a new Date with the day set to 0, it will assume the last day of the month. You can the use the following function get the number of days in a month:

```
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

The Javascript date object is leap-year aware, so you can use this function reliably.

You then just need to count the number of months between the start and end date and check each one to make sure the day number is actually present in the month. You can short-circuit this check if the day is less than or equal to 28.